# Types of authentication in azure?

Tags: azure

I am new to azure and was reading about the authentication part. There are two portal classic and ARM. I want to know by how many ways a user can be authenticated in azure.Is there any different way of authorization with Classic portal and ARM portal?

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by `different way of authorization with Classic portal and ARM portal?` especially the authorization part.

Comment: No. Yes. The *portal* works with Microsoft accounts and/or AD federation with your on-premise AD. It also supports two-form authentication. All of them work across portal versions.  The *services* offer a lot of authentication methods - some built-in, some enabled through code.

Comment: The authentication methods *are* documented in Azure's site.

Comment: I mean will there be any difference in authorization steps or any details required if a do the authorization with classic or ARM ?

Answer (score 2):

`Authentication` to me is the process of identifying who you are and `Authorization` is what you can do.

With this, in both old portal (which supports classic resources only) and new portal (which supports both classic and ARM resources), authentication is done via `Azure AD`. As mentioned in one of the comments, any user who is trying to access the portal must have a record in corresponding Azure AD (could be a native Azure AD account, sourced via a Microsoft account or AD federation). Without this, a user can't access either of the portal.

Now comes the authorization part.

The new portal is built on top of `Role-based access control (RBAC)` which provides granular access to resources. There are many predefined roles (Owner, Contributor, Reader) or you could create your own custom roles and assign roles to the users. Once a user logs in, they will only be able to perform operations that are allowed in the role. If a user tries to do an operation, the role doesn't allow it (for example, a user is in Reader role but tries to list storage account keys), they will be presented with "Access Denied" error.

The old portal also has roles but these roles are predefined and their scope is not granular as compared to RBAC roles. To the best of my knowledge, there are only 3 roles available in old portal - `Subscription Admin`, `Subscription Co-Admin` and `Account Admin`. If I am not mistaken, old portal can only be accessed by a user if they are either Subscription Admin or Co-Admin. Similarly accounts portal (to view bills etc.) a user should either be Subscription Admin or Account Admin. However once a user gets in to the portal, they can do everything. In other words, inside old portal a Subscription Admin and Co-Admin are the same. They can create resources, update them and even delete them. You can't have fine-grained control in old portal like you have in the new portal.

Answer (score 1):

A user will authenticate on Azure using a subscription. After that, the recommendation is to create new services using Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com) and the new services will be created using the ARM  (Azure Resource Manager) architecture. The previous version (a.k.a classic), allows users to create services based on ASM (Azure Services Manager).

With a subscription, users can be authenticated using REST APIs, Powershell, Azure Cli, Azure Portal, Azure SDK.